# Activity or Fragements for display of details in Android

Tags: android

I am working on android app development. I am designing a online shopping site in android.My question is what should i use to show the details of each chosen item ?
I mean if every time i use a new activity for each new item then it will occupy lots of space. Then what should I do ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fragment is better if you have a larger screen/and/or want to show more than one activity simultaneously. For instance maintain a view of a list and the selected item:

> For example—to continue with the news application example—the application can embed two fragments in Activity A, when running on a tablet-sized device. However, on a handset-sized screen, there's not enough room for both fragments, so Activity A includes only the fragment for the list of articles, and when the user selects an article, it starts Activity B, which includes the second fragment to read the article. Thus, the application supports both tablets and handsets by reusing fragments in different combinations

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

An activity (without a fragment) will provide the view of that one activity only. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dialog` in conjunction with `fragments` and a `listview` as well for some nice product viewing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will be defining only one fragment/activity for displaying details.
For each chosen item, instance of same activity/fragment will be created and displayed. So you need not to worry about size. You can pass some information about chosen item in intent while launching new activity/fragment.